# HibernateException Unable to construct requested dialect Oracle10gDialect

Tags: hibernate, jboss, persistence.xml, jboss-eap-7

We are getting below HibernateException while deploying our application in jboss EAP 7.2.
Could you please have a look and suggest some solution to this problem ? Thanks in advance.

> 2019-10-18 14:27:07,422 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 89) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."ddm.ear/apps.ddm.ddm-repository.jar#ddm-repository":
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."ddm.ear/apps.ddm.ddm-repository.jar#ddm-repository":
>   org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
>   service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
>                   at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:195)
>                   at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:125)
>                   at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:650)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to
>   create requested service
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
>                   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
>                   at Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to construct requested dialect
>   [org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect]
>                   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:84)
>                   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:51)
>                   at Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect cannot be cast to
>   org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
>                   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:74)
>                   ... 29 more

[pom.xml, Persistence.xml, Jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9BUt.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect cannot be cast to org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect

This likely means you are having duplicate classes on your classpath, making the JVM complain about an incompatible assignment. I'd suggest to check which jars are on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your hibernate configuration, hibernate.dialect(Probably in hibernate.properties) should be chosen corresponding to your oracle version For ex: Oracle8iDialect, Oracle9iDialect and Oracle10gDialect